# use lodash to lowercase internal array element

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this object

```
ob = {
 timePeriod: "Month",
 device: ["A", "B"]
}
```

when i use

```
x=_.mapValues(ob, _.method('toLowerCase'))
```

`x` is

```
 timePeriod: "month",
 device: undefined
```

it is not able to lowercase `device` array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array dont have toLowerCase function.
Change to below

```
x = _.mapValues(ob, function(val) {
  if (typeof(val) === 'string') {
   return val.toLowerCase(); 
  }
  if (_.isArray(val)) {
    return _.map(val, _.method('toLowerCase'));
  }
});

JSON.stringify(x) // {"timePeriod":"month","device":["a","b"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ob = {
    timePeriod: "Month",
    device: ["A", "B"]
}
var lowerCase = _.mapValues(ob, function(value){
    return _.isArray(value) ? _.map(value, _.toLowerCase) : _.toLowerCase(value);
})
```